# Minimize integral subject to integral constraint

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations

I am trying to find the function $f:[0,1]^2\to\mathbb{R}$ which minimizes the integral $$\iint_{[0,1]^2}f_{x}(x,y)^2+f_{y}(x,y)^2\,dxdy,$$ subject to the constraint $\iint_{[0,1]^2} f(x,y)^2\,dxdy=1$. I think I am supposed to use the calculus of variations, but I'm not even sure how to start.

Comment: You'd have to consider the constraint as a penalty and take the Lagrangian $L = f_x^2+f_y^2-\lambda f^2$. The E-L equation is $(\lambda + \triangle f)f + \|\nabla f\|^2 = 0$. I've used Green's first identity to solve for $\lambda$, but it still doesn't seem very good.

Comment: You have to clarify the notation here. If $f_x(x,y)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and  $f_y(x,y)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ then the smallest it could be is when $f(x,y)$ is a constant, and $f(x,y)=1$ satisfies the constraint. So that can't be what the question means because it's too easy:)

Comment: ? Perhaps related: middle part of __[Ideal Flow](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/jaar2017/ideal.htm)__ .

Answer (score 5):

For every function we have that $$f_x^2(x,y)+f_y^2(x,y)\ge 0$$therefore$$\iint f_x^2(x,y)+f_y^2(x,y)dxdy\ge0$$so take $f(x,y)=1$ and this is the only funcions satisfying our problem.